# How to limit database call to a random number to random number plus five?

Tags: php, mysql, random

I needed a random number limit to be 1-90, inclusive. So whatever random number I get to current random number + 5.

```
$query2 = $xxx->query("SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY tableid LIMIT FLOOR(RAND() * 90)  + 1, (FLOOR(RAND() * 90)  + 1) + 5");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to call `RAND()` twice.
As [limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html#idm139855752158224) says:

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

i.e.

```
LIMIT offset, max rows
```

So you can just do

```
LIMIT FLOOR(RAND() * 90) + 1, 5
```

Also considering that offset is zero-based, are you sure you want 1-90 and not 0-90?

---

It is also possible to generate the number php-size

```
$rand = rand(1, 90);
// if your $xxx->query supports positional parameters
$query2 = $xxx->query('SELECT ... LIMIT ?,?', $rand, $rand + 5);
// or without it
$query2 = $xxx->query(sprintf('SELECT ... LIMIT %d,%d', $rand, $rand + 5));
```

Comment: I want **(rand number(1-90))** to **(the previous random Number+5)**.

For example, lets say I have these id: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
variable first_random_number = random number(1 to 4), inclusive. 
I want (SELECT* FROM tbl ORDER BY LIMIT first_random_number, first_random_number+5);
But I can't do it like that in mysql so how can I do that?

Comment: So if the RAND() retrieves (for example) number 60, then you want retrieve all rows from index 60 to index 125?

Comment: Do you have explicit requirement to generate the RAND() in MySQL? Because it can also be accomplished in PHP — I've modified my answer to add it.

Comment: Umm no. If rand() retrieves(for example) number 60, then I want retrieve all  rows from 60 to 65.

Comment: so the limit difference is 5

Comment: So you want to retrieve 5 rows starting at offset 60?